# How to process data from fast websocket?

Tags: python, websocket

I need some help with websockets. How do i NOT PROCESS code if its already executing in a websocket? Here is some sample code below - do not worry about optimizing the code inside of "fancy_calculation" - I just want to only run this code if the function is not already running. How can I reduce the websocket delay by skipping over fancy_calculation if its already currently in the process of executing?

```
import websocket
import json
import datetime
import time

class Trading():

    def fancy_calculations(self, binancemsg):

        # In practice, these calculations would be fancier. They are simplified for ease of understanding
        curtime_GMT = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        time.sleep(2) # This represents a really complicated operation
        timestamp = float(binancemsg['data']['E']) / 1000
        delay = curtime_GMT - timestamp
        return delay

    # Process websocket data
    def on_message_binance(self, ws, message):

        binancemsg = json.loads(message)

        # Need a way to run this function ONLY if it has not been run before
        delay = self.fancy_calculations(self, binancemsg)

        # Messages keep on getting piled up on each other. As more and more messages get loaded, it takes longer and longer
        # to process the data - introducing more and more delays
        print('Websocket delay = ' + str(delay))

    def start(self):

        # Stream
        binance_stream = dict()
        binance_stream['BTC'] = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@ticker'

        threads = dict()
        self.message = ''
        threads['ws'] = websocket.WebSocketApp(binance_stream['BTC'],
                                                      on_message=lambda ws, msg: self.on_message_binance(self, ws, msg))

        threads['ws'].run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Trading
    x.start(x)
```

Comment: do you want to throttle calls to  fancy_calculations function as the events pile up or literally just skip the function for subsequent events until last on has processed?

Comment: skip the function until the last one has processed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the write Speed of MongoDB cannot match the speed of the input data which leads to the saved data lagging behind and eventually stopping the WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks - I"m not using MongDB though. My question is more around how to skip data from the websocket

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but it could do the job. Add a variable inside a class and change it when you run the function for the first time

```
class Trading():

    self.flag = False

    def fancy_calculations(self, binancemsg):

        # some code...
        self.flag = True
        return delay

    # Process websocket data
    def on_message_binance(self, ws, message):

        # Need a way to run this function ONLY if it has not been run before
        if self.flag == False:
            delay = self.fancy_calculations(self, binancemsg)
```

Comment: That’s a good idea… and I tried that… but it looks like the websocket still executes the code (and does not operate concurrently.) if you can find a way to make the websocket operate concurrently- you will be my hero :)